# Holding unordered_map element to a pointer/iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

Each time to find an element I use `find` and thus, I have a pointer returned to it (iterator would be better to describe it rather than pointer). But, in the case the element is not there, I go create it.

The problem is that after both cases I want to have something that will point to that element no matter if it existed or not (because I ensured that I created it). My solution is to use find (for the second time, which I guess is costly), but I think that there could be a unified way to hold a reference to the item without doing a second search (either by previous find or while creating the item).

Is this possible?

Comment: Please post the code you're describing rather than trying to describe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common pattern -- you can use `insert()` which returns an iterator whether something was added or not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, string> m;

    auto result = m.insert(std::make_pair(0, "Foo"));

    if(result.second)
       cout << "Inserted: " << result.first->first << " -> " << result.first->second << '\n';

    result = m.insert(std::make_pair(0, "Bar"));

    if(!result.second)
       result.first->second = "Bar";

    for(auto i : m)
       cout << i.first << " -> " << i.second  << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Inserted: 0 -> Foo
0 -> Bar
```

Comment: So each time, insert or not, this will return a reference to the map item, very good.

Comment: I would use `auto result = m.emplace(0, "Foo");` personally.  And for the second, C++17 will provide `result = m.insert_or_assign(0, "Bar");` .

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::unordered_map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert).

It's return value is `std::pair<iterator,bool>`, where boolean value indicates whether actual insertion took place or the value already existed. See documentation for return value:

> 1-2) Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element
>   (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting
>   whether the insertion took place.